# Convert Date from random date formatter to selected formatter in swift 3

Tags: ios, date, swift3, date-format

I am creating app in which I am accessing date as a string from external html file and want to save that date with particular date formatter. Currently I am doing as follows

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")

let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: yourDate)

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy"
updatedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!)
```

But this code works when I give first date formatter 'dd-MMM-yyyy'. If date from .html file comes in same format, this code works perfect. But if that date format is changed then this will give nil. I want generalise solution which will return me date in fixed format but could be in any format.

Comment: In this case, there is no chance you can get/create a valid date. Input date format should be a fixed format. Or you can create a common function with several types of date formatter, that you generally see in PDF file.

Comment: One possible solution would be to try against a predefined number of different formats that you expect to get as input and proceed when you got a match (a non `nil` output). I guess you _could_ use something like an `NSDataDetector` but be prepared for having to worry about misfires (seriously, don't do it for anything that data consistency is needed). Finally keep in mind that for something like '05-01-2019' is impossible to be interpreted correctly without any other information (since it is valid in both formats)

Comment: @Alladinian : I was planning to do the same. But I thought I would get any other way to do this. Anyway thank you.